# How many points per heart?

Tags: stardew-valley

Does anyone know how many points you need to get to the next heart? I kinda want to try and calculate how many times I need to give gifts to people for the next heart.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Friendship):

> Each heart is 250 friendship points.

You can gain friendship points by:

> - talking to villagers (+10 if the villager is in the middle of a special animation, like exercising or using a camera, otherwise +20; can only score once per day)
> - Completing a delivery quest for them (+150);
> - giving them a gift they like ([see Gifts](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Friendship#Gifts))
> - making certain choices in their heart events.

You can lose friendship points by:

> - not talking to a villager (-2/day);
> - giving them a gift they dislike (see Gifts);
> - hitting them with the slingshot;
> - rummaging through a trash can when they're nearby (-25, except Linus who doesn't mind).